# Problem with beamer in the math-mode for not showing parenthesis

Tags: beamer, math-mode

I have a problem with parenthesis. In beamer I write `$(a)$`, but it display just `$a$`.
Someone here may know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you use a standard setup, `(a)` should appear. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have the same problem, I think that is caused by a package, but I don't know which one...

Comment: I had he same problem, until I remove `\usepackage{pslatex}' from my preambule.

Comment: Same here with the package '\usepackage{lmodern}'